# How does Conditional Validation work in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

Looking through the rails code, I can't see where conditional validation gets executed... when you pass a string or an symbol to `:if` it supposedly does an `eval` for strings and a `send` for symbols... where does that happen?

Been trying to follow it through the code but I can't find where the `if` options are split into `send` or `eval` and how that all works. Just trying to learn and follow the through how rails does it.

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/validator.rb
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations.rb

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb#L421-#L450) is responsible for all the symbols, strings and lambdas being executed. Seems that Rails is using `activesupport callbacks` to implement validations.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, I kinda tracked it down to: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb#L65
But wasn't sure if thats where it went or what happened after.  Thanks!